# Read ExcelData using Python

Tags: python

I have an excelSheet, where the headers are in one column and respective values are in another column.
is there any way to read the data from excelsheet using python?
[Refer image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGEUP.png)

Read the excel data using python

Comment: `is there any way to read the data from excelsheet using python` — yes it is. Have you done any reseach yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried reading data in row wise. but here the data is in column wise.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far and a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have used pandas framework to read an excels sheet using read_excel function. but haven't tried with such data and i am not sure how to approach also.

Comment: how large is the file?  if its only two columns, and the 3 header names consistently repeat in that pattern, it might be simpler to convert to csv and write a custom read loop group those sets of rows.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety - Is it possible to do using pandas? 

data wise it's big file. just showed an example in my attached excel sheet.

Comment: @Alderven - Could you please suggest me, how we can approach these solution in simplerway.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the file exactly? just 'reading' the file with pandas is easy, and it seems you say you've already done that

Comment: @BrandonPardi - I have to populate it in a table.  but the data is in column wise.. Please refer attache screenshot in my Question

Comment: @Karun add to question input data in text format. Add to question expected result

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel sheet is confirmed to always repeat those 3 fields in the given pattern, then if you convert it to a csv via Excel, the following should load it into a dataframe for  you

Test CSV file `weirdexcel.csv`

```
EmpName,Ramu
EmpID,12345
EmpDesignation,Manager
EmpName,Srinu
EmpID,12346
EmpDesignation,Software Engineer
EmpName,Ravi
EmpID,12347
EmpDesignation,QA
EmpName,Shankar
EmpID,12348
EmpDesignation,Business Analyst
```

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd

expected_keys = ("EmpName", "EmpID", "EmpDesignation")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=expected_keys)

with open("weirdexcel.csv") as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    temp=[]
    count=0
    while True:
        try:
            name = next(reader)
            id = next(reader)
            designation = next(reader)
            nextEmp = {
                name[0]: name[1],
                id[0]: id[1],
                designation[0]: designation[1]
            }
            #nextEmp = {item[0]: item[1] for _ in range(3) for item in next(reader)}
            #print(nextEmp)
            df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(nextEmp).to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)

        except StopIteration:
            print("Done")
            break

print(df.to_string())
```

Output

```
   EmpName  EmpID     EmpDesignation
0     Ramu  12345            Manager
1    Srinu  12346  Software Engineer
2     Ravi  12347                 QA
3  Shankar  12348   Business Analyst
```

If there's any chance of the fields not always repeating in that exact pattern, some additional checking using the expected_keys or at least checking for the next appearance of EmpName to short circuit to the call to `pd.concat()` may be needed.

I tried using a dictionary comprehension to pull 3 rows at a time, but ran into some weird problems getting the data to unpack the way I wanted, which will probably be leading to my own post later today to figure out what I was getting wrong.

**Edit:**
I did finally figure out how to do this with a dictionary comprehension, but its a lot less readable as it took some trickery with the `:=` operator and a conditional statement to get the data out of next(reader).
Just adding it here for reference:

```
nextEmp={row[0]:row[1] for _ in range(3) if (row:=next(reader))}
```

Comment: This is what I expected. I will try and comeback of I have any questions on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read the Excel file as dataframe

```
input_df= pd.read_excel('file_path',header=None)
```

Create output dataframe

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['employee_name','employee_id','employee_designation'])
```

Taking values from input dataframe and loading them to output dataframe

```
for i in range(0, len(input_df), 3):
    output_df.loc[len(output_df)] = [input_df.iloc[i, 1],input_df.iloc[i + 1, 1],input_df.iloc[i + 2, 1]]
print(output_df)
```

This is the first time I am posting an answer in this site.
 Please  give a thumbs up if this code works.